# FB.Canvas.setSize() not working on IE

Tags: facebook, iframe, canvas

How can I resolve the resize of facebook app on IE ?
the FB.Canvas.setSize() is not working.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there's very little to go on in your question.  No example url, no code example.  I can only guess.  So here's where to start.

1) Be sure to include the Javascript SDK inside of script tags.

```
<script>
  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
   }(document));
</script>
```

2) Be sure to include the fb-root div inside of the body

```
<body>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    ...your html here...
</body>
```

3) Be sure to do the FB.init() and FB.Canvas.setSize() after the javascript SDK has had a chance to load.  Meaning do it inside of your window.fbAsyncInit

```
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID', // App ID
      channelUrl : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });
  };
```

4) Make sure you have specified your APP ID and also the correct location for a valid ChannelUrl